# R Replace Numbers with Logic Depending on Value

Tags: r

I have a correlation matrix in R, that I want to only see numbers > 0.5. Can I change this to TRUE/FALSE depending on the number? Or can I only display the values >0.5? I've tried filtering but that doesn't work.

ETA:
So I used

```
cors <- cor(data)
```

Which gave me a correlation matrix, say

```
    A    B    C    D
W   0.6  0.3  0.0  0.3
X   0.1  0.4  0.2  0.1
Y   0.7  0.2  0.1  0.0
Z   0.2  0.8  0.6  0.4
```

And now I want to easily show those values above 0.5. Let me know if you need more code!

Comment: 1 ) `mat > 0.5` to get `TRUE`/`FALSE` values  2) `mat[mat <= 0.5] <- NA` to to replace values less than 0.5 to `NA`. 3) `mat[mat > 0.5]` will give you the values greater than 0.5. Is that what you need?

Comment: Can you show us some code?

Comment: It could be, but I'm unsure how to use it (it's saying not found). Would you do something like?
'pairs <- mat > 0.5'
(The matrix is named "cors")

Comment: Yes, so you need to replace `mat` with `cors`. Try `cors[cors <= 0.5] <- NA`

Comment: That worked! Thank you so much!